# Error When Running setup:di:compile

Tags: setup-di-compile

I am trying to do compilation of Magento 2.2.2 installation and I am getting errors as shown below.

Kindly assist in how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

[root@www html]# bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 17 secs 310.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  A void function must not return a value in /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Request/CsrfValidator/Interceptor.php on line 24

Below it the content of the file

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator;
/**
 * Interceptor class for @see \Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator
 */
class Interceptor extends \Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
{
    use \Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator, \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState)
    {
        $this->___init();
        parent::__construct($formKeyValidator, $redirectFactory, $appState);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $action) : void
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'validate');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::validate($request, $action);
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('validate', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        } 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Check your php version. Or more in this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Comment: The php version installed is 7.1.33 for our Magento v2.2.2. Thanks.